# Python EasyGUI: Systray icon xor multiple windows

Tags: python, systray, easygui

I'm writing a simple program that gives you a message to take a break from sitting at your Computer every x minutes. However, I also need to be able to close the program without having to wait for a window to pop up after x minutes.

My ideas are that I either create a systray icon (I'm programming it for a friend who uses Windows) and add the possibility to exit it that way, or that I just add another window, which has an exit button and stays open all the time (less elegant).

From what I have read, it seems that the systray idea requires something more complex than easygui.

So, is there a way to implement any of those ideas with easygui and if not: what do I need to look at to get it working?

Thanks for your time and effort.